# How to delete different rows of a 3D tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, delete-row, tensor

For example, there is an 3D tensor like this:

```
a = tf.constant([[[1,2,3],
                  [4,5,6],
                  [7,8,9]],
                 [[9,8,7],
                  [6,5,4],
                  [3,2,1]],
                 [[0,8,0],
                  [1,5,4],
                  [3,1,1]]])
```

I want to delete the different rows from the three elements with indices as:

```
idx = [[1], 
       [0], 
       [2]]
```

The result would be like this:

```
re = [[[1,2,3],
       [7,8,9]],
      [[6,5,4],
       [3,2,1]],
      [[0,8,0],
       [1,5,4]]]
```

How to do it?

Comment: I know how to do it with loop. no loop please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First approach: using `tf.one_hot` and `tf.boolean_mask`:

```
# shape = (?,1,3)
mask_idx = 1- tf.one_hot(idx,a.shape[1])
# shape = (?,3)
result = tf.boolean_mask(a,mask_idx[:,0,:])
# shape = (?,2,3)
result = tf.reshape(result,shape=(-1,a.shape[1]-1,a.shape[2]))
```

Second approach: using `tf.map_fn`:

```
result = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.boolean_mask(x[0],1 - tf.one_hot(tf.squeeze(x[1]),a.shape[1]))
                   , [a,idx]
                   , dtype=tf.int32)
```

An example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],
                    [[9,8,7],[6,5,4],[3,2,1]],
                    [[0,8,0],[1,5,4],[3,1,1]]],dtype=tf.int32)
idx = tf.constant([[1],[0],[2]],dtype=tf.int32)

# First approach:
# shape = (?,1,3)
mask_idx = 1- tf.one_hot(idx,a.shape[1])
# shape = (?,3)
result = tf.boolean_mask(a,mask_idx[:,0,:])
# shape = (?,2,3)
result = tf.reshape(result,shape=(-1,a.shape[1]-1,a.shape[2]))

# Second approach:
result = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.boolean_mask(x[0],1 - tf.one_hot(tf.squeeze(x[1]),a.shape[1]))
                   , [a,idx]
                   , dtype=tf.int32)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(result))

# print
[[[1 2 3]
  [7 8 9]]

 [[6 5 4]
  [3 2 1]]

 [[0 8 0]
  [1 5 4]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! I chose the first approach. It works well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` (assuming `a` and `idx` as `numpy.ndarray`):

```
import numpy as np

columns_to_delete = idx.flatten()
mask = np.ones_like(a, dtype=np.bool)
mask[np.arange(a.shape[0]), columns_to_delete, :] = False
re = a[mask].reshape(a.shape[0], a.shape[1] - 1, a.shape[2])
```

and then convert `re` to tensor using `tf.convert_to_tensor`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. a is a tensor, not a list. sorry I didn't make it clear.